# Retain visited link color even after browser cache clear

Tags: html, css, browser

We are using css to change visited link color. However our customers using a common machine where after browser close cache gets clear.

I understood that this functionality is completely based on browsers history https://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy.

We would like to retain the link visited color irrespective cache clear.

Comment: Then save a list of the user's visited pages on the server side.

Comment: Unless you store each click on a link in some kind of database, this probably won't be possible. There is usually a good reason why a browser cache is cleared. If it is a common machine which is shared by different users, clearing the cache on close up is essential for privacy protection. You should not circumvent that.

Comment: @user3154108 I wouldn't mind a website remembering which of its pages I had visited.

Comment: @MrLister The point is that others should not be able to see which pages you visited. And if you don't mind, you can set your browser to not clear your cache on closing ;)
You could use Cookies or LocalStorage to store a page-specific history, but even those can be deleted by the user/browser, and if you use a Database, you need to identify your user as well with some form of session cookie.

Comment: @user3154108 Yes, so they will need a login system to keep track of their users. You know, I'm beginning to think this question is too broad. They haven't even mentioned what server-side platform they're using to achieve this.